# Agregar fila a una tabla con datos desde un modal

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery

si me pueden ayudar con esta duda de como pasar los datos llenados de un formulario que esta en un modal hacia una nueva fila en una tabla. Y que que se vaya acumulando cada vez que abre el modal para llenar el formulario, y la opcion de eliminar la fila.

Este es mi modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="myForm" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar accion a Clientecentrico</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tipo:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="70 - Experiencia">70 - Experiencia
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="20 - Trabajo con otros">20 - Trabajo con otros
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="10 - Formación formal">10 - Formación formal
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="comentarios" required="required" rows="5"
                                  class="form-control" name="message"
                                  data-parsley-trigger="keyup"
                                  data-parsley-minlength="20"
                                  data-parsley-maxlength="1000"
                                  data-parsley-minlength-message="Come on! You need to enter at least a 20 caracters long comment.."
                                  data-parsley-validation-threshold="10" placeholder="Accion."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Fecha fin:</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
                            <input type='text' id="fecha_final" class="form-control"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="myFunction()">
                        Cerrar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y la tabla es esta

```
<table id="tabla-acciones" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>Accion</th>
    <th>Fecha fin</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Aca el script que estoy intentando

```
$('#crearAccion').click(function () {
var tipo = $('#optradio').val();
var accion = $('#comentarios').val();
var fechafin = $('#fecha_final').val();

$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + tipo + '</td><td>' + accion + '</td><td>' + fechafin + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: @alanfcm si me olvide poner el script, ahi esta.

Comment: Que problemas tienes con tu codigo?

Comment: @alanfcm que no crea una nueva fila en la tabla con los datos del formulario que esta en el modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas dos botones distintos, uno para mostrar el modal y luego cuando aceptas, agregar la fila.  Algo asi:

```js
$('#crearAccion').click(function () {
  var tipo = $('input[name="optradio"]:checked').val();
  var accion = $('#comentarios').val();
  var fechafin = $('#fecha_final').val();

  $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + tipo + '</td><td>' + accion + '</td><td>' + fechafin + '</td></tr>');
  $("#myModal").modal('hide');
});
$('#crear').click(function () {
  $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="myForm" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar accion a Clientecentrico</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tipo:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="70 - Experiencia">70 - Experiencia
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="20 - Trabajo con otros">20 - Trabajo con otros
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="10 - Formación formal">10 - Formación formal
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="comentarios" required="required" rows="5"
                                  class="form-control" name="message"
                                  data-parsley-trigger="keyup"
                                  data-parsley-minlength="20"
                                  data-parsley-maxlength="1000"
                                  data-parsley-minlength-message="Come on! You need to enter at least a 20 caracters long comment.."
                                  data-parsley-validation-threshold="10" placeholder="Accion."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Fecha fin:</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
                            <input type='text' id="fecha_final" class="form-control"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Cerrar
                    </button>
                    <button id="crearAccion" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button data-toggle="myModal" id="crear">Crear</button>
<table id="tabla-acciones" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>Accion</th>
    <th>Fecha fin</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
```